# Can't catch clipboard event in a background service android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, background-service

I'm trying to catch a clipboardChanged event in a background service

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TranslateService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}


public class TranslateService extends IntentService implements ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {

    public TranslateService() {
        super(null);
    }

    public TranslateService(String name) {
        super(name);
        ClipboardManager manager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        manager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

It should make a toast "Working" if the event is fired.
I also tried to create the ClipboardManager and add the  listener in onHandleIntent and it didn't work either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When the default constructor is called, you are not adding the listener to `ClipboardManager`.

I think you meant to use `this(null)` in your default constructor instead of directly calling `super(null)`.

```
public TranslateService() {
    this(null);
}
```